# Where does my friend live? 7

Tags: knowledge, language

<sup>*Other questions in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71693+%22Where+does+my+friend+live%3F%22+is%3Aq).*</sup>

---

My friend, Jimmy, is a puzzle creator. He posted this for his country on a social media account.

> 972 mulini a vento rossi con croci bianche ciascuno ha un canguro

**Do you know where he is?**

Hint:

> There are five countries in this sentence, which are clues to the final answer.

Comment: Does this require any knowledge of the Italian language? If so it needs a language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New answer number 2:

> India

Clues:

> 972 refers to the area code of Israel for phone numbers, the italian passage translated says 'red windmills with white crosses each has a kangaroo'. Red windmills refer to Netherlands, a country famous for their windmills. White crosses refers to Denmark, because of its flag. Kangaroos refer to Australia because Australia are famous for them. So you have 5 countries, Israel, Netherlands, Denmark, Italy and Australia. Take the first letter from each and that spells India.

Comment: Better now?????